# Python: different types of field name in string formatting

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting, field-names

Consider the following dictionary:

```
dic1 = {1:'string', '1': 'int'}
```

Let's apply string formatting:

```
print("the value is {0[1]}".format(dic1))
result --> the value is string
```

but how can I get '`the value is int`' as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be this.

```
print("the value is {0}".format(dic1['1']))
```

The `{0}` only acts as a place holder for text to be put into the string.  So an example use would be.

```
>>> x=1
>>> y=2
>>> z=[3,4,5]
>>> print "X={0} Y={1} The last element in Z={2}".format(x,y,z[-1])
X=1 Y=2 The last element in Z=5
```

You can also do this to change things up. The numbers reference which argument to use from the format command.

```
>>> print "X={0} Y={1} The last element in Z={0}".format(x,y,z[-1])
X=1 Y=2 The last element in Z=1
```

See now that I changed my string to `Z={0}` it is actually using the `x` in the `.format(x,y,z[-1])` command.

Comment: Thank you. Worked! But I thought it would be easier to have one argument for example and use it in multiple placeholders. For instance, something like your example: I would call z once in format function and use in multiple placeholders like: "Z1={0[0]}, Z2={0[1]}".format(z)

Answer (score 1):

It works,

```
print("the value is {0}".format(dic1['1']))
```

**Edit** to answer @Afshin's comment

You can use * operator before an iterable to expand it within the function call. For example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print("X={0} Y={1} The last element in Z={2}".format(*a))
```

OR

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
print("X={x} Y={y} The last element in Z={z}".format(**d))
```

Comment: Thanks. Please check out my comment on @Zack's answer.